# jetty ssl with client-auth throws null cert exception

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, cxf

I am trying to run jetty in ssl mode with client authentication.
I pass keystore.But instead of passing truststore, i import my certificate into java/jre/lib/security/cacerts. please find the jetty.xml configuration

```
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
        <Arg>javax.net.ssl.keyStore</Arg>
        <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="." />/../workspace/conf/xyz.ks</Arg>
    </Call>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
        <Arg>javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword</Arg>
        <Arg>abc</Arg>
    </Call>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setProperty">
        <Arg>javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType</Arg>
        <Arg>JKS</Arg>
    </Call>

Socketconnector

<Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
            <Set name="Port"><SystemProperty name="port"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">600000</Set>
            <Set name="keystore"><SystemProperty name="javax.net.ssl.keyStore"/></Set>
            <Set name="keyPassword"><SystemProperty name="javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"/></Set>
            <!--Set name="truststore"><SystemProperty name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore"/></Set>
            <Set name="trustPassword"><SystemProperty name="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword"/></Set-->
            <Set name="needClientAuth">true</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
```

Now when i hit the url `https://localhost:1234/xyz?wsdl` i get bad_certificate exception which is caused due to null cert chain.

i) can java cacerts be used to configure jetty?
ii) is it because of the webservice call because in the logs it is shown as the server is started.

I am using jetty 6 and cxf 2.6 webservice.

thanks,
Keerthi.

Answer (score 0):

You should try hitting your URL from a browser, after adding your client certificate to your browser certificate store. By the way you will know if your error is due to server or client side misconfiguration.

Comment: I think he has already tried this from browser as mentioned in the question!!